# After upgrading a solution from VS2015 to VS2017 all client apps that reference a dll that uses System.Net.Http also need to reference System.Net.Http

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

I move a solution from VS2015 to VS2017. I have a WebAPI.dll that has helper functions in it that make API calls using System.Net.Http. My client ASP.NET applications reference this WebAPI.dll so they can simply call a function such as GetProducts().

In VS2015 I never needed my clients to reference System.Net.Http NuGet package to use the WebAPI.dll.

Now I get the following error when calling one of the functions in the dll:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

The only resolution is to add the System.Net.Http NuGet package to any Class Library or Web App that references and uses this WebAPI.dll.

Can someone please explain why this is the case?

Comment: Did you change the MVC version or the .NET Framework Version as part of the move from VS 2015 to VS 2017? Did you change the code in any other way as part of the move?

Comment: @mjwills They are mostly class libraries.. for example a DAL that references and calls functions from WebAPI.dll to return data. Is there anything I would have to do in the .csproj? Wouldn't VS2017 take care of that when opening the solution it anything was necessary? FYI the WebAPI project is a .net core class library that was upgraded by VS2017 from project.json to .cjproj...